# How to create a generic collapsible table with React & Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a generic table with collapsible rows, I make a simple table like from this link (https://www.bekk.christmas/post/2020/22/create-a-generic-table-with-react-and-typescript) but I can't handle collapsible rows with it.

Can I get some help to make it?

Comment: Have you done it in JavaScript?

Comment: No, with typescript.

Comment: Learn one thing at a time instead of following a random tutorial which is about introducing typescript into a react project